# Importing Windows Live Mail Email Accounts into Evolution

Tags: evolution

I was wondering if it's possible to get Evolution Mail in Ubuntu to be able to import a Windows Live Mail email account export, I have multiple email accounts and lots of email messages attached to each account and and being able to import them all into Evolution would be nice. Is there a way to do this?

The exports from Windows Live Mail are in a .iaf format which seems Microsoft specific.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post mark as [SOLVED]: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1392034 
I hope this can be useful for you or give you ideas to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but this for contacts. I am talking about Email messages along with email accounts

Comment: Hi James, I search around and find this: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=647703 is for Thunderbird. So you can import Windows Live Mail to Thunderbird and after that export to Evolution. I don't know nothing for WLM, I found different solution for this topic: one of them is to export to Gmail and after that to Evolution, or to use convert software from WLM files to Mbox files.

I found and this: http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/hotmail-or-windows-live-mail-evolution.

I hope something to work for you. Good luck.